# How to create interlinear gloss in R markdown?

Tags: r, alignment, markdown, r-markdown, text-alignment

I would like to create an interlinear gloss in R markdown, in which glosses are aligned with the words that they are providing information about.

In the following example, I want the left edge of each character string in the German sentence on top to be aligned with the left edge of each character string of the English beneath it:

1. Ich habe den Bub gesehen

   1sg.NOM  have.1sg.PRES  DEF.ACC.SG  boy.ACC.SG see.PERF.PART

So the left edge of "boy.ACC.SG" should be aligned right beneath the left edge of "Bub."

Packages like `gb4e` do this in TeX, but I don't know how to align text this way in markdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some pandoc filters available that might actually help, e.g. [pangloss](https://github.com/daemanos/pangloss), which is python-based and can be installed via pip. To use it in an rmarkdown document, specify in yaml that pangloss should be used as a filter:

```
---
title: My title
author: Somebody
output:
  pdf_document: 
    pandoc_args:
      - --filter
      - pangloss
---
```

Pangloss actually seems to use the gb4e package for pdf outputting, so you may have to include it in your preamble, so that the whole thing becomes

```
---
title: My title
author: Somebody
output:
  pdf_document: 
    pandoc_args:
      - --filter
      - pangloss
    includes:
        in_header: add_to_preamble.tex
---
```

and add_to_preamble.tex must contain the line

```
\usepackage{gb4e}
```

The actual examples are included in markdown the following way (this is the example given at pangloss's github page)

```
As you can see in the following examples, pangloss is really easy to use:

(@) Jorge  llama             a  Maria.
    George calls-3s.PRES.IND to Maria
    'George calls Maria.'
(@ex-french) Aussi, vous pouvez          avoir    de multiples   exemples.
    also   you  can-2p.PRES.IND have.INF of multiple-PL example-PL
    'You can also have multiple examples.'

You can even refer to examples, as in (@ex-french).
```

This seems to be pretty much still a work in progress, though.